# What does the line strength mean in terms of spectral lines?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, spectroscopy

In my previous astrophysics lecture we were discussing the spectral types of stars. We were looking at the absorption features of dwarf stars in different spectral classes at a particular luminosity class. At the end of the discussion he wrote down that line strength in these graphs depends on the temperature of the stars and the line widths are determined by the density in their atmospheres (collision broadening). Looking it up online, it seems that how strong a line is expressed as an equivalent width. In which why are line widths and line strengths separate terms in my lectures statement?

Comment: [All explained here?](http://ircamera.as.arizona.edu/astr_250/Lectures/Lecture_15.htm)

Comment: Aren't they using line width as a definition of line strength?  If so I will clarify with my professor on his definition of the terms.